# How to properly setup and work with Git Flow

Tags: git, git-flow, smartgit

I'm experimenting with Git in a finished (1st phase) project since I would like to have `release`, `feature`, `hotfix` and least but not less `tags` and I think Git Flow is for this. So I have setup from Smartgit as pic below shown:

[image]

Now I started a new **release** because I end this 1st phase and I client consider this as a *"stable"* release. So I get this:

[image]

But after read [here](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/) I'm still not sure what the next step would be. I mean how I push or pull my code from `master` branch to `pdone-stable-1`? Or I am complete wrong on this and release is just some kind of tag?

Comment: Perhaps you should read AND understand the meaning behind the different branches types in git flow by reading the initial post about it: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next step in git-flow is

- Merge `release/pdone-stable-1` to `master`
- Merge `release/pdone-stable-1` to `develop`

You would also tag the `master` merge as a release, but it sounds like you don't want to tag.

These two actions make your code available in `master` where it can be deployed and in `develop` so your team is all in sync.

Comment: My sources right now are in `master` meaning I have just started today with git-flow, should be the nexts steps the same as you said on your answer? Think as "I developed everything in master branch until today, before I didn't have any of this enabled"

Comment: Ah, then you don't want a release yet. From `master`, start your `develop` branch, then from `develop` start all of your `feature/` branches. Merge your `feature/`s into `develop` as they're ready, then eventually start a `release/` branch from `develop`. After the release is tested and has any fixes, etc., merge it into `master` and `develop`.